# How do I detect if a wx.Menu has been destroyed

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm porting an application from:

- Python 2.5.4
- 2.8.10.1 (msw-unicode)

to:

- Python 3.7.9
- 4.1.1 msw (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5.

The following snippet gives different results. In particular it seems that previously you were able to detect if a wx.Menu had been deleted by just doing "if widget".

If that doesn't work anymore, how can I check whether a wx.Menu has been deleted?

```
import wx

app = wx.App(redirect=False)
menu = wx.Menu()
menu.Destroy()
print(bool(menu))
```

- 2.8.10.1 = False
- 4.1.1 = True

Comment: normally I would simply use `menu = None` after `Destroy()`

Comment: That fails if you've got two Python variables pointing at the same WX widget.

Comment: you should always use only one variable for every widget.

Comment: BTW: if widget doesn't have some functionality then you can use it to create own widget with this functionality - `class MyMenu(wx.Menu)`, or you could write to authors to show this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check how it used to work as I have no access to a legacy system.

However you can write a simple function to check whether or not the item is deleted by looking at its Window property. Just pass the reference to the menu into the function *check_menu*

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
    menu = wx.Menu()
    self.check_menu(menu)
    menu.Destroy()
    self.check_menu(menu)


@staticmethod
def check_menu(menu):
    try:
        menu.Window
        print('active')
    except RuntimeError:
        print('deleted')
```

Gives the results

> active

> deleted

Comment: The weird thing is that other wx classes (wx.TreeCtrl for example) implement the __bool__ operator. wx.Menu is the only exception I was able to find. I'll go with your approach for now.